How to use Python Pandas Groupby for multiple columns?
I have a dataframe that I am trying to do some calculations on and add a few columns.
Here is an example of the input dataframe:
df1:

Index    Type    Product    Late or On Time
0         A       X              On Time
1         B       Y              Late
2         C       Y              On Time
3         C       X              On Time
4         C       X              Late
5         B       X              Late
6         A       Y              Late
7         C       Y              On Time
8         B       Y              Late
9         B       X              On Time


I am trying to create a new dataframe that has 3 new columns and gets rid of the "Late or On Time" column. The first new column will be a Product/Type combo count that counts how many times each product/type combo appears in the dataframe. The second column will count how many of each product/type combo are late, and the third column will count how many are on time. Here is an example of the output I am going for:
Index    Type    Product     Product/Type Count    Late Count    On Time Count
0         A       X              1                     0                1
1         A       Y              1                     1                0
2         B       X              2                     1                1
3         B       Y              2                     2                0
4         C       X              2                     1                1
5         C       Y              2                     0                2

I am able to get the Product/Type Count using this line of code, but I do not know how to get the other two columns:
df2 = df1.groupby(['Type', 'Product']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'Product/Type Count'})

Use another group by to group on your lateness column, unstack, and join.

You can create dummy columns that you sum along for late/ontime separately. Then include those back in the aggregation:
from io import StringIO

buffer = StringIO('''
Type    Product    Late or On Time
 A       X              On Time
 B       Y              Late
 C       Y              On Time
 C       X              On Time
 C       X              Late
 B       X              Late
 A       Y              Late
 C       Y              On Time
 B       Y              Late
 B       X              On Time
''')

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(buffer, sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
print(
    df.assign(
        _late=lambda d: d['Late or On Time'] == 'Late',
        _ontime=lambda d: d['Late or On Time'] == 'On Time',
    )
    .groupby(['Type', 'Product'], as_index=False)
    .agg(**{
        'Product/Type Count': ('Product', 'size'),
        'Late Count':         ('_late', 'sum'),
        'On Time Count':      ('_ontime', 'sum'),
    })
)
#   Type Product  Product/Type Count  Late Count  On Time Count
# 0    A       X                   1           0              1
# 1    A       Y                   1           1              0
# 2    B       X                   2           1              1
# 3    B       Y                   2           2              0
# 4    C       X                   2           1              1
# 5    C       Y                   2           0              2


With your df1, construct:
df2 = df1.groupby(['Type', 'Product']).size().rename('Product/Type Count')
ext = df1.groupby(['Type', 'Product', 'Late or On Time']).size().unstack()

Then just join on the indexers.
>>> df2.to_frame().join(ext).fillna(0)
              Product/Type Count  Late  On Time
Type Product                                   
A    X                         1   0.0      1.0
     Y                         1   1.0      0.0
B    X                         2   1.0      1.0
     Y                         2   2.0      0.0
C    X                         2   1.0      1.0
     Y                         2   0.0      2.0

Intermediate variables as used here need not be assigned.

What you want is a crosstab with margins:
out = (pd.crosstab([df['Type'], df['Product']],
                   df['Late or On Time'],
                   margins=True, margins_name='Product/Type Count')
         .iloc[:-1].rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
      )

Output:
  Type Product  Late  On Time  Product/Type Count
0    A       X     0        1                   1
1    A       Y     1        0                   1
2    B       X     1        1                   2
3    B       Y     2        0                   2
4    C       X     1        1                   2
5    C       Y     0        2                   2


import pandas as pd


data = {
    'Index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B'],
    'Product': ['X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X'],
    'Late_or_On_Time': ['On_Time', 'Late', 'On_Time', 'On_Time', 'Late', 'Late', 'Late', 'On_Time', 'Late', 'On_Time']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
'''
   Index Type Product Late_or_On_Time
0      0    A       X         On_Time
1      1    B       Y            Late
2      2    C       Y         On_Time
3      3    C       X         On_Time
4      4    C       X            Late
5      5    B       X            Late
6      6    A       Y            Late
7      7    C       Y         On_Time
8      8    B       Y            Late
9      9    B       X         On_Time
'''

df['Late'] = df['Late_or_On_Time'] == 'Late'

res =  df.groupby(['Type','Product']).agg(
Late = ('Late','sum'),
On_Time = ('Late', lambda x : len(x) - sum(x)),
Product_Type_Count = ('Product','count')    
).reset_index()
print(res)
'''
 Type Product  Late  On_Time  Product_Type_Count
0    A       X     0        1                   1
1    A       Y     1        0                   1
2    B       X     1        1                   2
3    B       Y     2        0                   2
4    C       X     1        1                   2
5    C       Y     0        2                   2
'''

